# VS2012 fails to publish a specific file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, publishing

I have a MVC project created using Visual Studio 2012. I'm trying to publish this using the same IDE (vs2012). The publish succeeded and everything seems fine with `1 succeeded, 0 failed and 0 skipped` publish status.

Problem is, one of the file, a `.cshtml`, wasn't copied. There wasn't any much difference with the other files. I checked its properties and it was the same with the others. I checked it in the project file (`.csproj`) and it was included there. Then why it isn't copied/published? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the properties on the .cshtml file and make sure it's set to copy to destination ...

Comment: Copy to destination property was set to 'Do not copy'. But all the other files are set the same and they work fine when published..:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that the file's `Build Action` property was set to `none`. I changed it to `Content` and it works fine..ugh..